# Re-write access adp / sqlserver to C# .net?

Tags: ms-access

I am a non technical person and have a small company who has been supporting my companies software for a number of years.  The solution works well and permutations of the solution has been with the current IT service provider for over 15 years.  I recently got a more established IT firm to do a general audit on the software.  The current solution uses access as a front end with sqlserver 2005 as the database.  The company who did the audit presented a list of faults amongst others that the technology is outdated, the solution is not scalable, bad design, non user friendly interfaces, tables not normalised, tables has no referential integrity, non use of proper coding standards and naming conventions, no application security only database security etc.  The firm who did the audit proposed that the solution must be re-written and offered to do so.  The current service provider aknowledges some of the findings but assures me that it poses very little or no risk to my business.  To re-write the application will cost a lot of money.  I am in a difficult situation and would appreciate some technical advice.  I basically need to know if my business is at risk running on the current technology. I have a maximum of 70 concurrent users working on the system at a given time

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you value Joel's [word](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html), i would say that you are indeed, risking alot here.

Rewriting stuff was and will never be a safe thing to do for a company.

Answer (score 2):

Before you go view your problem from the technical perspective, you must assess how critical the application is to your business.  It sounds as though you have a functioning application.  If it delivers consistent behavior AND you have no need for upgrades / new development, you may want to leave it alone.  We software developers love to complain about everyone else's code, re-write other's work with "elegant" solutions.  That means money.

However, you have an investment that may need maintenance, and when you have the underlying code and database in dis-array, you will incur more cost because the application does not lend itself to be modified.  You'll want to get a feel for how much change you need to support.  Given that it has been in production for 15 years you've had a good run, so you don't have much risk there.

To do a re-write will cost you, because you need to recreate what the app does, and since the supporting database and program seem to be "de-normalized" and unstructured, it's going to a big effort.  There are advantages to have a clean database model because it will be easier to do reports, export to Excel, etc. AND should you want to modify it the developers will have an easier time figuring out what to do.

To spend money to get what you already have requires that you challenge the firm to detail what additional benefits you'll receive.  Are these benefits beyond what you're getting today, and will this firm deliver on their promises?  Will your company be better off if the database is "normalized" but you receive no other benefit than what the current app gives you?  Keep these in mind before you make the jump to a new platform.

Answer (score 2):

To boil it down into simple terms, ask yourself these questions:

1. Are you having problems with the software currently?  Are users complaining about the user interface, or is it particularly hard for new users to pick up the software when using it?  Is data being lost or corrupted at any stage, or are you having problems retrieving reports from the database?
2. Do you currently, or in the future are you likely to need modifications?  If your software is badly written, modifications will be more costly, and more likely to break the application and cause downtime in general.

If the answer to both questions is no, then you likely don't need to rewrite the software.  You have to remember that good software developers see badly written software and want to re-write it properly - as well as this, there is money for them in developing the software, so their view isn't totally unbiased.

Like others have said, re-writing a system has its own share of risks - old bugs that were fixed a long time ago can rear their heads again, new bugs can be introduced, the developers of the new system can totally miss the point and make the system less usable than the previous system.

If there are problems with the current system though it may be worthwhile to consider having the system re-written by competent developers - if you opt to go this route however, make sure to get feedback from your current users, especially the 'expert' or 'power' users, to ensure that the system will fulfill all of their requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Fix the problems in the existing app. It will be much cheaper, can be done incrementally, and if done properly, will result in a more maintainable app.

The suggestion to replace the ADP front end sounds like pure prejudice/ignorance to me -- they don't sell Access development so they want to build you an entirely new app.

On the other hand, the advice about the back end sounds like something that you shouldn't wait to fix (though it could require a lot of work, since existing data likely won't fit proper RI).

The front end and back end problems are two separate issues, and can be handled independently (though the app may need to be updated to reflect changes in RI -- impossible to say without a case-by-case evaluation).

I would hire a competent Access developer with ADP experience to handle the project. This will be much cheaper than the complete rewrite and you won't sacrifice any functionality, nor will you re-introduce bugs that have already been addressed in your existing app. It can also likely be done incrementally (depending on what the problems are and how they need to be solved).

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions offered by the "more established IT firm" are pretty common for access/sql server projects. The suggestion is almost always re-write them as web applications.

I just did this myself last year -- took an MS Access front-end/SQL Server back end application, and rewrote the access part as a C#/ASP.Net website. We enjoyed better performance and more flexibility as a result of the switch, but the old front end had been around long enough that we never did get back all of the functionality that we used to have before the rewrite.

If you're actually seeing 70 concurrent users, and none of them are experiencing performance issues, and your corporate network is secure enough, then you may lose more by rewriting the application, at least in terms of functionality. On the other hand, this may be a good chance to evaluate "what works" and "what could work better"--and enhance workflows.

Excellent use of coding standards doesn't necessarily translate to an excellent application.

Answer (score 1):

What prompted the audit? Does their solution address this issue?

Let's do the math:
People:  70
Avg. Hrs Using software/Day: 2 (Conservative)
Salary/Hour:  $8.00 (Really Conservative)
Business Days/Year:  250 (Took out weekends & vacation/sick)

Cost of labor using application:  70 * 2 * 8 * 250 = $280,000 / Year (Could go over 500K)

How much improvement can you get?  5%, 10%, 25% 
How much will the new application cost?  50K, 100K, 200K

If you are able to save this time, will your users be freed up to do revenue generating activites or will they just have more time to surf the web? You may want to create some worker efficiency factor: 90%, 75%

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer... Most of the "risks" of using Access are surmounted by using SQL server as the backend. You already said your current solution works.

So it boils down to your future plans. If your existing application isn't missing any functionality that can't be provided via access I would just stick with what you have. 
If you need new features I would consider a few things.

1. Are they something Access can't provide or do well (ex: Internet-facing Solutions)?
2. What is the potential benefit reaped by having the new features?
3. What is the potential cost incurred by *not* having the new features?
4. Can you put a dollar figure on 1 & 2?
5. How much to develop the solution in Access?
6. How much to develop the solution in C#

In other words, always do the [CBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost-benefit_analysis) :) Better yet, do you own CBA, then ask both companies to provide you with one, and compare for fun. In the worst case you might get your existing company to come down on their price to retain you as a client.